# Javascript Regular Expressions - accept non-zero for first number in amount

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to accept a number that does not start with zero but later values can be zero.
I am using var.replace(/[^1-9]/g, ''); which do not let me to enter 0 at all.

valid:

```
10
9990
```

invalid:

```
01 
0999
```

i should not be able to enter 0 at first place. If 0 is entered it should get replace with '' blank that is the logic

Comment: more context (code) please

Comment: using the expression in directive - Inputvalue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); @FelixSchildmann

Comment: Please, edit your question and add valid numbers and invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if the first value value isn't zero, you can simply do a substr:

```
Inputvalue.substr(0,1) !== '0'
```

---

If you want all leading zeroes replaced:

```
Inputvalue.replace(/^0+/, '');
```

The `^` means 'string begins with', then 'one or more' (`+`) zeroes.

---

If you want all leading zeroes before a digit(`\d`) replaced:

```
Inputvalue.replace(/^0+\d/, '');
```

The `^` means 'string begins with', then 'one or more' (`+`) zeroes.

---

If you want to get the first digit after the zeroes:

The `^` character means 'start of string'. You say it could be `000001`, the `1` is not at the start of the string, so that will never match.

I find it helpful to define what I want in text:

- I want the first digit, only one -> `[1-9]`
- Starts with <sup>(`^`)</sup> with one or more <sup>(`+`)</sup> zeroes -> `^0+`

That results in `^0+[1-9]`.
We only want to store the digit, so we place that in a group: `^0+([1-9])`

```js
const examples = [
  '123', // no starting zeroes
  '0123', // match
  '000123', // match
  '132000123', // no matching zeroes, dont match the end either!
];

console.log(examples.map(function (example) {
  const matches = example.match(/^0+([1-9])/);
  return example + ' -> ' + (matches !== null ? matches[1] : 'no match!');
}));
```

Comment: I entered (/[^1-9]+([1-9])/g, ''); for my case is it right?

Comment: I suggest you read my post again :) Regex is tricky. You now have "must start with 1-9, at least on character. Then capture [1-9] to do something with it

Comment: I think you missunderstood the question. They want to reject numbers that begin with zero.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer. Just the original answer, might as well add a few flavours :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead to be sure that the 1rst digit is not zero:

```js
var test = [
'0123',
'000001',
'abc',
'123',
'102030',
];
console.log(test.map(function (a) {
  return a + ' :' + /^(?!0)\d+$/.test(a);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

The escape `\d` matches any digit from 0-9.
Since you said that the number must not start with zero, we can start by writing `[1-9]`.

So, the final regex will look like: `/^[1-9]\d*$/g`.

This will match any non-zero positive number, provided that's the entire string.

You can auto-validate form inputs with this regex.

`<input pattern='^[1-9]\d*$'>`

Comment: Hi. your answer wont work because of the same mistake OP has made. You force it to start with a `[1-9]`, but it wont match if it starts with one or more zeroes: https://regex101.com/r/10ICR7/1

Comment: I thought it said doesn't start with 0 but can have 0 later on