# Regex if clause or checking

Tags: regex

Hello I'm new in regex but is it possible to be checked if first digit is 0 next digit to be in range 1-9. How it is possible to be written?

0133428789 if first digit is 0 second digit can't 0 again. Thanks for help before.

Comment: TLDR, `^0[1-9]` (see [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61366413/3832970))